# Automatic input to program

Tags: python

I have a code that needs to get an input from the console.
I am doing it to be able to debbug a code with input from console becuase pycharm does not allow me to pause during execution.
I want to be able to provided the input i want beforehand , i.e to provide it automatically through the code as if it was provided from the console.
Is this possible?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: What do you mean "pycharm does not allow me to pause during execution"? From my experience, pycharm does stop to wait for input when you use `input()` in your code. How are you getting input in your current code? What happens when you run your program in pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `input()`, PyCharm will pause execution to wait for input just as if you run in the console.

Alternatively, you can use `sys.argv` to take command line parameters. You can add these parameters to the run configuration in pycharm.